# Images become very light

Tags: ios11, xcode9-beta

I wonder, icons which already worked in iOS 10 is not working on iOS 11 (image become very light). While compiling through Xcode 8.3.3 is working and with Xcode 9 beta 4 it's become very light. Advice on the same.

Answer (score 0):

I found that images with color description file would show welll but the images without that would show very light. Fix the images which does not have color description will solve your problem even if it is a very heavy work.
[info of two images left image shows well ,right image shows very light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PriYE.png)